# Can Amazon Elastic Transcoder concatenate two videos

Tags: video, amazon-web-services, transcoding

That is, take foo.mp4 and bar.mp4 and produce foobar.mp4, which is simply foo.mp4 followed by bar.mp4?  (For extra credit, if it can do this, can it also combine foo.mp4 and bar.mov?)

I might also want to do some other transcoding things, but right now my concern is with the concatenation question.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

The answer seems to be "no", at least for now (Sept 2013) -- https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=490206&#490206

Answer (score 2):

AWS has added the ability to define multiple inputs for a job, which will join the clips into a single clip.

If you go through the console and look at the GUI there, you'll see an "+Add Another Input" option.
[Console Input options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YjYRR.png)

You can see the request input takes an array.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elastictranscoder/latest/developerguide/create-job.html

Right now (April 2017), they don't have the ability to set the transition as you would in a video editor (e.g., dissolve, dip to black) so you'll want to check the transition of the output clip to see what it ends up with. You can clip each input separately to get the desired result (e.g., cut off fades out/in).

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

> You can configure Elastic Transcoder to stitch together parts, or clips, from multiple input files to create a single output. This allows you to create a single output from different inputs, such as separate recording sessions or highlights from a game.

Ref: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elastictranscoder/latest/developerguide/clip-stitching.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes , This would be possible now *(July 2018)* .
First you should create 3 Buckets on S3 , 1 for input , 1 for output and 1 for the thumbnails , Next you should create a pipeline to link your input bucket to your output bucket , Next you should create a Job on the pipeline using AWS elastic trans-coder,
When creating a job make sure you specify multiple inputs (with matching file types) If you want to use different file types it is also possible but it will take more time , Pipelines can hold multiple Jobs , so you should first create a job that trans-codes all videos in Bucket A (input bucket ) to the same file format in Bucket B (output bucket ) , to continue with concatenation you specify 2 inputs foo.mp4 and bar.mp4 and make sure you only specify  **ONE**  output , after you create your job check your output bucket and you should see your video.
NOTE: when choosing the output preset make sure it matches both your inputs and outputs